# Open QGIS project using PHP command

Tags: qgis, php

We are using a intranet geoloket (html). I would like to share some QGIS projects using PHP.

This is the code I start with:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=MapInQgis.qgz");<br>
header("Content-type: application/**octet-stream**");<br>
readfile("MapInQgis.qgz");
```

Which content-type must I use to make sure my collegues can open the MapInQgis.qgz-file?

Answer (score 1):

`qgz` is a zip file, so you can try the mime type `application/zip`